# Unable to save the invoice magento

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice

One of my recent project in Magento there are two stores. First is Default and second is Mobile Store. On mobile devices Mobile Store works. We face an issue when user do purchasing from mobile devices. We are not able to generate Invoice of that order from admin. Whenever I try to Submit Invoice it throw an error "Unable to save the invoice.". But if order comes from Default store it works well. I did some research over this and found in InvoiceController.php file $transactionSave->save(); throw exception. Full transaction code is below;

```
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($invoice)
                    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
```

Does anyone have ideas how to fix it?

Comment: If you enable logging under System > Configuration > Developer and try to invoice again Magento will generate log files on your server under MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/. This should include more information as to why it can't save the invoice.

Comment: Can't reproduce, closing. Please update with debugging/log info.